# Update value database in MySQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I want to update "todo" in table user, where the value "username" is the same as the value in my code _naam. What I have so far (kind of copied from my "read" command):

```
private bool Todo_updaten(string _todo)
    {
        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmdUpdate = new MySqlCommand();
        cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE `user` SET `todo`=@todo WHERE `username` LIKE '" + _naam + "'";
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todo", _todo);
        cmdUpdate.Connection = connect;
        MySqlDataReader tbupdaten = cmdUpdate.ExecuteReader();
        if (tbupdaten.Read())
        {
            tbTodo.Text = tbupdaten.GetString(0);
            connect.Clone();
            return true;
        }
```

I get an error at my bool todo_updaten, which says: not all code paths return a value.

Comment: Add another `return` at method's end.  `false`, I suppose, given your logic.  Yours _only_ returns _if_ the code enters the block, so it's not lying to you.

Comment: Your `return true` statement is inside your `if (tbupdaten.Read())`. Be sure to return something outside as well. e.g.  `else { return false; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the return type of your `Todo_updaten` function is `bool` so you always need to return any `bool` value from it. At present, you are returning true only if the condition is fulfilled but if not then you are not returning anything. Which is wrong so you can return false in else statement to overcome it, or any of your custom logic. But make sure you are returning a `boo`l value from the function always.

```
if (tbupdaten.Read())
   {
       tbTodo.Text = tbupdaten.GetString(0);
       connect.Clone();
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not return anything if `tbupdaten.Read()` returns false, because you only have a `return` in that `if block`.

Also when updating you database you should call `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteReader`.

```
private bool Todo_updaten(string _todo)
{
  db_connection();
  MySqlCommand cmdUpdate = new MySqlCommand();
  cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE `user` SET `todo`=@todo WHERE `username` LIKE @naam";
  cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todo", _todo);
  cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", _naam);
  cmdUpdate.Connection = connect;
  cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
  return true;       
}
```

The `ExecuteNonQuery` also returns the number of rows affected if you want to check anything.